# Table Schema with multiple columns in fact table referring to one column in dimension table

Tags: database, powerbi, schema, dimensional-modeling, fact

To start off, I am creating a table schema in Power BI with the use of R to wrangle all of my data.

Here is a simple example of my issue. I have a table with ID numbers and several demographics related to each ID. In this case, you'll see 3 demographics related to each ID with a true/false for each demographic (in my work situation, I actually have 95 demographics).

| ID | Female | Veteran | Government |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 2 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |

So, let this be the fact table.  A dimension table would look something like this:

| Demographic | Key |
| --- | --- |
| Female | 10 |
| Veteran | 11 |
| Government | 12 |

I need to create a relationship between these two tables. I'll be using Power BI, so I can only use one direct relationship. The main purpose is to be able to create visualizations that will filter down on a user's selection.  For example, if the user is interested in how many ID's are female *and* veteran, the graph would only show ID #3.

As is, the dimension table will not work because there are no keys in the fact table to connect the two.  For it to work properly, I would need one, and only one, column in the fact table with a key that connects to the dimension table. That would look like this:

| ID | Female | Veteran | Government | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | 10 |
| 2 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | 12 |
| 3 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | 10, 11, 12 |
| 4 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |  |

This doesn't work because Power BI won't "search" for a key within the "Key" column. It can only have one key per row, not a set of keys, as far as I'm aware. I could potentially make keys that would be the combination of demographics. So, for ID #3, the key would be "10_11_12" and then have that exact key within the dimension table, too. But, as mentioned above, I have 95 demographic columns and that's a right massive mess.

I have also tried to make the initial fact table above long instead of wide:

| ID | Demographic | Value | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Female | True | 10 |
| 1 | Veteran | False | 11 |
| 1 | Government | False | 12 |
| 2 | Female | False | 10 |
| 2 | Veteran | False | 11 |
| 2 | Government | True | 12 |
| 3 | Female | True | 10 |
| 3 | Veteran | True | 11 |
| 3 | Government | True | 12 |
| 4 | Female | False | 10 |
| 4 | Veteran | False | 11 |
| 4 | Government | False | 12 |

However, Power BI will only aggregate the data.  That is, for our example of female *and* veteran, the graph will show any ID that is female as well as any ID that is veteran. So, the result would show ID's #1 and #3, but it should only show #3 (I need female *and* veteran not female *or* veteran).

Any ideas of how to get a dimension table and fact table to work well together for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your Fact Table

(ID,Female, Veteran, Government)

Your dimensions would be

DimFemale, DimVeteran, DimGovernment, etc.  Each Dimension would have two rows and probably only a single column.  So you typically just don't use dimension tables when the you don't have any data other than the dimension key.

> I am wanting a filter in the filter pane that has a drop-down of all 95 demographics.

That's not a dimension table, that's a child fact table with bi-directional cross filtering.  Just have (Id, Demographic) and only add the ones that are TRUE.

Comment: Yes, that would probably work in this example, but I have 95 demographic-type columns in my actual data (not the 3 in this example) and that would be a ton of dimension tables.  :)

Comment: So just don't create dimension tables.  If a dimension has no columns other than its key, then there's no point in creating a separate table.  PowerBI doesn't _need_ dimension tables; you can filter and group by fact table columns.

Comment: Does the ID refer to a person i.e. Female, Veteran, Government are all attributes of a person? If so, why not create a Person dimension with all these attributes?

Comment: Thanks, David.  Your edits made the most sense and I added another table that had bi-directional cross-filtering with just TRUE's.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You only need the first table, no need to complicate.

If the user wants to know the number of ID's that are female and veteran, you would have a slicer/filter for female and veteran and the results would be filtered accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this and I understand what you mean.  However, I have 95 demographic-type columns (not just the 3 in this example).  So, I am wanting a filter in the filter pane that has a drop-down of all 95 demographics.  If I put a slicer for each filter, then there will be 95 slicers. Hence, the reason for wanting the dimension table because that "Demographic" column of the dimension table becomes my 1 filter in the filter pane with all 95 demographics (or 3 in this example), if that make sense.  I just need it to be able to cross-reference the original table, which I haven't got yet.

Comment: But if you want to pick 4 items in the demographics you still have to select where the 4 are all true, or do you mean that you only "assign" the values where true?

Comment: I believe that when you select multiple values in a slicer the behaviour is OR rather than AND, so you'll always have some trouble with it. One solution could be to use your last table and then have slicers 1 to N where you establish the filter by creating a special measure that reads the selection on each slicer and then filters with an AND condition. You'd still be limited to just N slicers.

Comment: Another option could be to have 95 slicers. Pick the top 10/20 most used, put them in a hidden panel, add a show more option that shows the others with some sort of pagination or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, Joao.  These are all great ideas and I tried them out, but the one that ended up being easiest is David Browne's suggestion below after making edits (the bi-directional cross filtering with a table of only TRUE's).  I really appreciate your time and help!